# Create table with Boolean column type from a VARCHAR column source table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE response (response_id INT, utime INT, 
                     question_id INT, response VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO response (response_id,  utime, question_id, response)
VALUES (5,1459542506,11,1),(5,1459542506,12,0),(5,1459542506,13,0),
  (5,1459542506,14,0),(5,1459542506,15,0),(7,1458210291,11,0),(7,1458210291,12,1),
  (7,1458210291,13,1),(7,1458210291,14,0),(7,1458216077,15,1),(10,1458212391,11,1),
  (10,1458212391,12,0),(10,1458212391,13,1),(10,1458212391,14,0),(10,1458212391,15,0)
```

Which stores survey response of people's activity in a designated hour. Each  `question_id` represent 1 question from five possibilities. The response to a user indicates his choices from all the possibilities. Where s/he did not answer is assumed to be false.

```
question_id  |   activity
 ------------+----------   
11           -   sitting
12           -   walking
13           -   standing
14           -   running
15           -   jogging
```

These responses are stored in column `response`, for value of each question. So example the response from `response_id=5` is sitting, and no other activity, `response_id=7` is walking, standing, jogging.

Unfortunately, in the source table, `response` is defined type `VARCHAR` not `BOOLEAN`.

I want to create a new table that describes the activity for each `response` where such an activity is reported. Here's how I go:

```sql
CREATE TABLE target_table AS
  SELECT response_id, to_timestamp(utime), response = 'true' activity
  FROM response; 
=> SELECT 15

-- but then
SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE activity IS TRUE
=> SELECT 0
```

Equally, activity column values all reported as `f`

```sql
response_id  activity_day       activity
   5        2016-04-01 21:28:26+01  f
   5        2016-04-01 21:28:26+01  f
   5        2016-04-01 21:28:26+01  f
```

**Required output**

I would like to have `target_table` in the for:

```
response_id  | activity_day        | activity 
-------------+---------------------+---------
    5         2016-04-01 21:28:26    sitting
    7         2016-03-17 10:24:51    walking
    7         2016-03-17 10:24:51    standing
    7         2016-03-17 10:24:51    jogging
   10         2016-03-17 10:59:51    sitting
   10         2016-03-17 10:59:51    standing 
....
```

NOTE: I provide this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ve2Wk1fe)

Comment: In your sample data your `response` column is filled with `0` and `1` (despite being a `varchar`). But you never insert the string `'true'`. So why do you expect that `response = 'true'` would ever be true based on your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Create the target_table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE target_table AS
  SELECT response_id, to_timestamp(utime) AS activity_day, response = '1' activity
  FROM response
```

After this selecting the TRUE answers:

```sql
SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE activity
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/P_pk-qA3)

This new table (target_table) will have been created with the following columns:

```sql
select 
     column_name,
     data_type
  from information_schema.columns 
  where table_name='target_table';
```

output:

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| response_id | integer |
| activity_day | timestamp with time zone |
| activity | boolean |