# CREATE TABLE where columns' values are derived from BOOLEAN expression of columns´ in source table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My previous question was not understood well,  so I reformulated it here. Having this as the source table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE response (response_id INT, utime INT, 
                     question_id INT, response VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO response (response_id,  utime, question_id, response)
VALUES (5,1459542506,11,1),(5,1459542506,12,0),(5,1459542506,13,0),
  (5,1459542506,14,0),(5,1459542506,15,0),(7,1458210291,11,0),(7,1458210291,12,1),
  (7,1458210291,13,1),(7,1458210291,14,0),(7,1458216077,15,1),(10,1458212391,11,1),
  (10,1458212391,12,0),(10,1458212391,13,1),(10,1458212391,14,0),(10,1458212391,15,0)
```

In the table are the results of users' survey. So each user (`response_id`) has an answer to each question (`question_id`). There are 5 questions in all. The response to each question by the user is stored in `response` column. Response takes 1 of 2 possible values: a `0` or a `1` (unfortunately this was defined as VARCHAR in the source table).

The `question_id` stand for:

```
id      |  answer
--------+---------------
11      -  sitting
12      -  walking
13      -  standing
14      -  running
15      -  jogging
```

**Question**

How do I create a table having say 6 columns, `response_id, sitting, walking, standing, running, jogging` with all columns (except the first as BOOLEAN type), so that `sitting` is assigned `1` or (`true`) if `question_id=11` and `response=1`, otherwise `0` (`false`). Also `walking` is assigned `1/true` if `question_id=12` and `response=1`, and `0/false` otherwise, etc.

**Expected output**

In the given example, I should have:

```
|response_id|sitting|walking|standing|running|jogging|
+-----------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|     5     |   1   |   0   |   0    |   0   |   0   |
+-----------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|     7     |   0   |   1   |   1    |   0   |   1   |
+-----------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|    10     |   1   |   0   |   1    |   0   |   0   |
+-----------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: How is this different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744651/create-table-with-boolean-column-type-from-a-varchar-column-source-table)

Comment: That was my previous question, reformulated here since it was not well understood there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to transpose the table. If so, then:

```
SELECT * FROM
    crosstab ('select response_id, question_id, response from response order by 1,2') AS aresult (response_id int,
        sitting varchar(1),
        walking varchar(1),
        standing varchar(1),
        running varchar(1),
        jogging varchar(1));
```

may help you.

Comment: Yes, Is there a way to cast the values from `VARCHAR` to `BOOLEAN` after transpose?

Comment: Yes, simply replace `response` with the `response::BOOL` and change the return types to `BOOL`. dbfiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/NxgHJHA-

Answer (score 1):

I wrote sample query for you:

```
select 
    response_id, 
    max(case when question_id = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as "sitting", 
    max(case when question_id = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as "walking", 
    max(case when question_id = 13 then 1 else 0 end) as "standing", 
    max(case when question_id = 14 then 1 else 0 end) as "running", 
    max(case when question_id = 15 then 1 else 0 end) as "jogging" 
from response
where response = '1'
group by response_id 

Result: 
response_id     sitting     walking     standing    running     jogging
5               1           0           0           0           0
7               0           1           1           0           1
10              1           0           1           0           0
```

Comment: I am wondering why the `group by` clause?

Comment: @arilwan - without group by you will see unnecessary duplicate data, basically a separate line will appear for each `response=1` and `response_id` will also show repeatedly